# Extensions (Chrome etc.) sending browsing data, is it theoretically possible to prevent that?

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, history, malware-detection

Chrome's chrome://extensions/ say "Warning: Google Chrome cannot prevent extensions from recording your browsing history" when enabling the [x] Allow in incognito. It seems to imply that uploading the history elsewhere cannot be prevented. Technically, why is this not preventable? Is it not possible to add a switch [x] Prevent extension from sending data to external servers?

Basically all extensions have the "Read your browsing history" warning. The concern is that I have no idea which extensions are possibly sending away data about everything I do on the browser, selling all my web behavior to 3rd parties.

https://discuss.howtogeek.com/t/warning-your-browser-extensions-are-spying-on-you/12394 names a few bad extensions, but certainly there are many more. https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/gygx7y/your-anonymous-browsing-data-isnt-actually-anonymous explains the simple techniques which may make all your web history virtually public.

Comment: "why is this not preventable?" - Chrome wasn't programmed to not allow it.  "Is it not possible to add a switch ...."  - If you were to modify the source code of Chrome, compile your changes, and use that version instead it certainly is possible.

Comment: So it is possible, great. I think that would be extremely important. Of course there are also other ways for 3rd parties to spy and give out the data, but this has to be one of the worst loopholes, in my opinion. Without the knowledge, pretty much everything done online could leak out with great detail (personal information included). Is this not seen as a problem?

Comment: What do even use these extensions? What do you want them to do for you? What permissions are going to give them, even if you have to fork the source code to do it?

Comment: "_Technically, why is this not preventable?_" **How is that even a superuser question?** It reads like a theoretical programming question (how do you write a web browser), a security question, or a software engineering question.